# eliminate mySQL sub query

Tags: mysql

how to make this into a single query using JOIN or something else, to eliminate the sub query

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT CONCAT(n.first_name, " ",n.last_name)
    FROM network n, PROFILE p 
    WHERE p.net_name = n.uid AND n.user_id = o.user_id) user_name, 
    (SELECT CONCAT(n.first_name, " ",n.last_name)
    FROM network n, PROFILE p 
    WHERE p.net_name = n.uid AND n.user_id = o.reff_id) reff_name, 
    o.*
FROM postback o
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a start:

```
SELECT CONCAT(n_user.first_name, ' ', n_user.last_name) AS user_name,
       CONCAT(n_reff.first_name, ' ', n_reff.last_name) AS reff_name,
       o.*
  FROM postback o
  JOIN network n_user
    ON n_user.user_id = o.user_id
  JOIN network n_reff
    ON n_reff.user_id = o.reff_id
;
```

Your current query will include rows of `postback` where there actually is no corresponding `user_name` or `reff_name`, whereas the above query will not; if you want to retain that behavior, change the above `JOIN`s to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s.

Also, your current query has joins to `profile`; I'm not sure why. The effect of that is to filter out any rows of `network` that don't have corresponding rows in `profile`. Is that intentional? If so, is it to force the subqueries to only return a single row (instead of multiple), or is it to force the subqueries to return `NULL` (instead of non-`NULL`)? That will affect the design of the `JOIN`-based query.

Comment: I think the second join to network should be on n_reff.user_id = o.reff_id

Comment: @BrianHoover: Oops, fixed, thanks. What's a Cartesian join between friends? :-P

Answer (score 0):

This SHOULD work.  What I'm not sure about is why you are joining on profile in both your subqueries.

```
SELECT CONCAT(users.first_name, " ",users.last_name) as user_name,
    CONCAT(reff.first_name, " ",reff.last_name, 
    o.*
FROM postback o 
  join network reff on o.reff_id = reff.user_id
  join network users on o.user_id = users.user_id
```